# How to turn multiple comma separated values in a row into a unique value sql 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Data looks like this:

```
declare @table1 table (ReportName varchar(200), email varchar(100))
insert into @table1 values ('Finance report', 'tony@mail.com, Nico@email.com, greg@email.com')
                          ,('Producer report', 'laura@mail.com, josh@email.com')
select * from @table1
```

[image]

I need it like this:

```
  **ReportName       email**
Finance report  tony@mail.com
Finance report  Nico@email.com
Finance report  greg@email.com
Producer report laura@mail.com
Producer report josh@email.com
```

Comment: `STRING_SPLIT`, and stop storing your data in a delimited format and fix your design.

Comment: Does the order of the items in each list have any significance, e.g. "To:" followed by "Cc:"? [`String_Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) proudly proclaims: "The output rows might be in any order. The order is _not_ guaranteed to match the order of the substrings in the input string."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply` and split the string:

```
select t1.reportname, s.value as email
from table1 t1 cross apply
     string_split(replace(t1.email, ', ', ','), ',') s;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=58dbc9dd5293e3532fbec1d12a862d99) is a db<>fiddle.